# PHP function run time

Tags: php, wordpress

Kind of a basic question, but I have a page similar to this example:

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Temp
*/
?>

<?php
function myFunction($urls) {
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
       echo $row['field'];
    }
}

$url1 = $_POST['urls'];
$urls = explode("\r\n",$url1);
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php if (get_option('professional_integration_single_top') <> '' && get_option('professional_integrate_singletop_enable') == 'on') echo(get_option('professional_integration_single_top')); ?> 

    <div id="content-top" class="top-alt"></div>
    <div id="content" class="clearfix content-alt">
        <div id="content-area">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part('includes/breadcrumbs'); ?>

            <?php if (get_option('professional_integration_single_top') <> '' && get_option('professional_integrate_singletop_enable') == 'on') echo(get_option('professional_integration_single_top')); ?>

            <div class="entry clearfix post">
            <?php
                        myFunction($urls);           
                ?>
                <h1 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                <?php if (get_option('professional_page_thumbnails') == 'on') { ?>

                    <?php $thumb = '';
                    $width = 184;
                    $height = 184;
                    $classtext = '';
                    $titletext = get_the_title();

                    $thumbnail = get_thumbnail($width,$height,$classtext,$titletext,$titletext);
                    $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"]; ?>

                    <?php if($thumb <> '') { ?>
                        <div class="thumb alignleft">
                            <?php print_thumbnail($thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height, $classtext); ?>
                            <span class="overlay"></span>
                        </div> <!-- end .thumb -->
                    <?php }; ?>

                <?php }; ?>

                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p><strong>'.esc_html__('Pages','Professional').':</strong> ', 'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>
                <?php edit_post_link(esc_html__('Edit this page','Professional')); ?>

            </div> <!-- end .entry -->

            <?php if (get_option('professional_integration_single_bottom') <> '' && get_option('professional_integrate_singlebottom_enable') == 'on') echo(get_option('professional_integration_single_bottom')); ?>

            <?php if (get_option('professional_show_pagescomments') == 'on') comments_template('', true); ?>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </div> <!-- end #content-area -->

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    </div> <!-- end #content -->
    <div id="content-bottom" class="bottom-alt"></div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**EDIT**:

I have updated the code to reflect the exact code I'm using.

Why are the `myFunction`  `echo` outputs within the `someFunction` function are appearing at the bottom of the document instead of right after `$somestring`?

How can I change this code so the `myFunction` `echo` outputs will appear in the correct place?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any calls to output buffering functions?  `ob_X`, like `ob_start`, `ob_flush`, etc, etc.

Comment: Is that the **exact** code you're using, which has the described issue?

Comment: @Sn0opy you are right, I should have added the original code. I edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it has something to do with your Wordpress theme. I tested it on my Wordpress blog and it works well. The function echos the value on the place I executed it. Please check your `header.php`. I think *d3v3us* is right and is something to do with output buffering.

Comment: Actually, I've just used the default Wordpress theme, and I'm using exec-php plugin to run the code, I call the function from within the post but still getting the results at the bottom, beneath the footer.

Comment: Dies exec-php have a footer hook? If so, your code will always be displayed at the end of your page.